# Cannot receive my item in-game, because Steam client won't connect

Tags: steam

My 30 day Steam restriction until I am able to purchase items from the Steam community market is ending today.

On Google Chrome, on the Steam website, it says I am able to purchase, so I bought a TF2 item, but the Steam client won't connect so I cannot receive my item. The Steam client claims I have no friends list (I have 3 friends), I have no fund currency (I have $13.91) and I have not bought any game (I have bought 1 game).

I can see the item I have bought in my profile inventory, but because Steam client won't connect, I cannot receive my item in-game.

How do I fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure you are using the same account in the Steam client as you are using in Google Chrome.

Comment: screenshots might help

Comment: Do you see the item in your inventory _on the Steam client_? Either way, you should propably contact Steam's support, because this looks really weird. I'd also suggest signing out and back in on the client.

Comment: No, did and did. :/

Comment: The steam client inventory just shows what items I have in-game, It doesn't show me what I have bought.

Comment: It's beginning to sound more and more like you've somehow managed to make 2 seperate accounts. (With same name and e-mail? Maybe even password.) Doesn't sound like something that sould even be possible, but that's the only explanation I can come up with for this behaviour.

Comment: Username, and password are the same. Steam client actually logged me in for me.

Comment: One more thing I'd check is the purchas history on both Chrome and the client. The market and game purhcases should be visible there and if the two are using the same account, the lists shouls be identical.

Comment: It says it's not authorized... Steam client is completely blank in the history.

Comment: Those are two different accounts. telltalestories and telltalestoires.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Zooming in on both screenshots, it seem you have one account named `telltalestoires` and one account `telltalestories`. Your money and games are on the account `telltalestories`.

Login with your correct account name and password and you should see all your money, games and items again.

Comment: You should contact steam and just outright delete your misspelled account.  This will confuse you again in the future.